# Unable to display contacts photo android

Tags: java, android, photo, contactscontract

I'm trying to display contacts using `Contactscontract`.
By now I'm able to read and display every contact name and phone number but I don't know how to display the thumbnail.

```
public class Display extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> imgContact = new ArrayList<String>();

    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // adding
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                        checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(Display.this, checkedcontacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
            imgContact.add(image_uri);
        }

        phones.close();
    }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        ImageView img;        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
             return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
              /*  vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);*/
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_txtCondition);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_txtMake);
            img= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
            img.setTag(position);
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }
}
```